# How to get Android error code of an application which crashes abnormally

Tags: android

I am trying to get the error code of an application which crashes abnormally. I am able to get *error cause*. For example:

> 1. "01-31 11:45:08.459: E/AndroidRuntime(680): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException "
> 2. "Caused by: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.foo/.bar}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml? ".

But I am not able to get the *error code* from logs. Is there any way to get it?

Comment: you mean to say want to write this log to a file ?

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
> ```

The poor guys can't make it easier than this to identify the error!

Answer (score 0):

This exception is due to you have not declared your activity in manifest file, add your activity to manifest file, by open manifest file-> select application tab-> select add-> browse your activity and save manifest file.

Comment: Thanks for your reply jitendra.But i want to track the abnormally terminated applications error code.I am getting the error cause but i need to get error code of that cause.

Comment: there is no error code, and its exception, just trace your log, there would be a full stack trace of exception, and according to the exception you are expected to fix the issue.

Comment: My job is not to fix those error or exceptions ,my job is to get the error code of that exception .is there any API to get those error code .

Answer (score 0):

You are not declared your activityfile name in manifest file. You can declare this code within the application tag.

```
   <activity android:name=".activityfilename">
   </activity>
```